# Laravel Backpack Controller - Cannot work out how to add logic to the script on Create method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-backpack

I have installed Laravel 6 with Backpack 4.
I have created a form with 3 fields:

- Title
- Slug (set as hidden field)
- Content

Upon saving the data I would like take the title and save it as a slug with the Laravel Helper:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
$slug = Str::slug('Laravel 6 Framework', '-');
```

I cannot work out where I should place this code.
In a normal Laravel app I would put it into the store() method, first set the slug as "nullable" in the validation and then apply the helper method before saving the slug to the database.

But with Laravel Backpack, I am lost.....

Any idea please?

Thank you.

Comment: no worry, I decided not to use backpack, spending too much time looking for basic things....

Answer (score 2):

Backpack uses Controller and Models, so you *can* [overwrite the Controller's store method](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/crud-operation-update#callbacks) if you want.

But for this use case, I recommend you change your Model. That's because your string should be sluggified no matter where the request comes from - a front-end form or an admin panel form. So it's better to have this logic in one place - the model, rather than repeat it in multiple places in your app. In Laravel, you can easily do this using a [Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) in your model:

```php
    public function setSlugAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['slug'] = \Str::slug($value, '-');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Tabacitu, I will go back the old way with a boilerplate from laravue. The main issue is that the primary goal when paying for these tools is to make us gain a lot of time. But having to remember all the syntax and where things have to go vs a normal Laravel installation is difficult(we have no time for this). At least having a visual builder like Infyom or Quickadminpanel should be a priority so we do not have to remember how to write a field, relationships or type a command line.This is really where everyone lose time as we keep going forward and backward in docs.

Comment: @Benny It is sometimes difficult to learn new tech.but in the end i believe Backpack has saved me a TON of time. I started using Laravel over plain PHP and it was difficult because i had to keep switching back and forth between Laravel docs even though i know PHP. I'm willing to bet your experience when learning laravel was similar but now, after learning it, would you ever go back to plain PHP? I feel the same about Backpack, there is a (IMO, small) learning curve, but now, I probably won't be going back to plain Laravel - its easy enough in most cases to override Backpack functionality  :)

Comment: Hey Benny. I am here just to give you my view point as the solution is already provided. Backpack integrates very well with Laravel. There are some glitches but the project is very active and fixing/adding features has been flowing good. In terms of time saving i cannot stress how much time you could spare using a tool like backpack. A GUI is on roadmap. Other tools have their advantages and disavantages we are not doing comparison here. In the end, you should go with the one you feel most confortable, but hey, sometimes a little pain brings some great benefits :) Wish you the best.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to give it another go :-)

Comment: Where I am not sure is about the field "slug", I tried to set it as hidden and even remove it but each time I get this:   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'slug' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `extra_pages` (`title`, `content`, `published_at`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Terms and Conditions, <p>kjhkjhkjh</p>, 2020-01-14 00:00:00, 2020-01-21 21:03:38, 2020-01-21 21:03:38)            .Now I have set the mutator as show above in my model, why would Laravel still tells me that the slug field has no default value? Thank you.

Comment: Ok I have spoken to someone on Laracast who says that the reason I am getting this error is because the slug field is empty and the mutator must receive something as a value in order to function(I thought it would work as soon as th method is called...I was wrong). How to pass the title value to the string field in the setupCreateOperation() please?

Comment: For some reason Tabacitu's answer did not work for me, the mutator was completely ignored. As a workaround, I used a setNameAttribute mutator, and I set the $this->attributes['slug'] inside of it based on the value of name...kind of hacky but it works